# The D program to launch doesn't exist in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, d

I'm just trying to set up a community version of the Visual Studio 2017 on my x64 PC (Windows 10) to program in `D` based on dmd compiler. In particular, I can build my snippet, but running the code returns the following error:

[image: The program to launch does not exist]

As I checked the similar questions, people often refer to a `.json` file corresponding to a solution. However, I have no idea whether it is really related to that. Anyway, here is the content of the `Test.json` file:

```
[
 {
  "name" : "Test",
  "kind" : "module",
  "file" : "Test.d",
  "members" : [
   {
    "name" : "std.stdio",
    "kind" : "import",
    "line" : 3,
    "char" : 8,
    "protection" : "private"
   },
   {
    "name" : "main",
    "kind" : "function",
    "line" : 5,
    "char" : 6,
    "deco" : "FZv",
    "endline" : 20,
    "endchar" : 1
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Any help?!

Comment: Assuming this is with Visual D - you might have more luck asking on [the IDEs subforum on the D forum](https://forum.dlang.org/group/ide), which is monitored by Visual D's author. I don't know if he checks Stack Overflow.

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev: Thanks for addressing that forum. I did open a thread there, as well.